# do not send notification when user is offline in IOS app [PHP]

Tags: php, ios, codeigniter, notifications

For sending the IOS notification, we have to send a device token with request. Then we save the device token in database `users` table.

When the user logs in, we store the device token in a column as per the device token notification goes to user.

However, when user logs out, device token is removed from the `users` table
and those notifications go a-miss from that user.

How can we handle this scenario that whenever someone logs in, the device can then send all those notifications?

Comment: you don't need to delete token after logout

Comment: if we dont delete that token even then the notifications goes on to the user device 
user will be logout and notification will keeps on going to user device

Comment: What exactly your issue is? You want to stop sending notification if user is not using application even though he was logged in previously.

Answer (score 0):

Save the notifications in the database for the user according to both user-id and token. When user is logged out remove the token, for newly generated notifications only save the user-id.
When user login update the records for the user with new token.